# Merge two System Workbench for STM32 Projects

Tags: stm32, hal, stm32cubemx

I configured with STM32CubeMX the UART interface for my Nucleo F446RE, it's using HAL Driver, and i want to connect it to a USB to UART Bridge so it can communicate with my GUI.
The other Project has all the programm code and it don't uses HAL Drivers.
Is there any way to merge these two Projects in System Workbench for STM32 together?

Comment: No. You have to do it manually

Comment: How can i do it manually?